# Is there any way to display record in crystal reports using database views without completing full cycle?

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports

I have created desktop application for Shop store. I am using crystal reports and C#.net. I have a problem in crystal reports. When i display the record it will not display either all the tables that i have linked in database view have records. E.g: I have 4 tables in database. One is main table have primary key and other three have its foreign key. Now i create the view of these four tables. After that i run the application and i have store data in one two or three tables. In this case it will display empty report either i have save record in fourth one table. What is the solution for this that i have record in one or two tables it will display me report. Thanks!

Comment: Does your application has a dataset to bind to Crystal reports?. If it is did you check your dataset before binding to crystal report.

Comment: Your question statement is different from your description.

Comment: Yes i have created a dataset for binding reports and i have check the dataset but still its same issue.

Comment: In my question statement Full Cycle means that my example given in my description. What is the solution for this that i have record in one or two tables it will display me report?